# SQL Server 2008 R2 Replication Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been attempting to configure SQL Server 2008 R2 (Standard) for replication between two instances running on Windows 2008 R2.  Both machines are on an internal AD domain (2008R2 domain).  The issue I am having is specifically with the subscription process being unable to push transactions (yes, doing transactional replication) from the distributor to the subscriber.  It is using a domain user (sqlrepl_distrib) which is in the domain users group by default to do this.

The error from the logs is:

Login failed for user 'XXXX\sqlrepl_distrib'.  Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error.  Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: ]

I have tried numerous things to get it work, but the only way I could get the subscription to work was to use my domain admin login (which is obviously unacceptable as a permanent solution).

The sqlrepl_distrib user has permissions as db_owner on both the publisher and subscriber database, as well as the distribution database, so that shouldn't be related to the issue.  SQL Server is configured for Windows authentication only.  I verified the user/pass also works by logging into the domain with it.  DBs and MSSQL instances are owned by the domain administrator, I think this may possibly be the problem, but not sure.

I have also tried to disable UAC on both SQL Server machines, but this did not help (yes I rebooted).

Hoping someone would have a clue as to what's going on.  I am fairly new to SQL Server, so I expect it could be something dumb, but Google has failed me to find a solution (the error that comes up in google seems to be with users being unable to access SSMS, which isn't my problem... that works fine).

To setup the replication, I followed the guide from Microsoft at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337389.aspx.  It does not mention this particular error.  I tried 3 times to setup the process all over again with the same results.

Anything pointing me in the right direction would be helpful (but please don't point me to a 1000 page long MSDN article and expect me to parse through that).

Thanks!

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but did you try logging into the distributor windows server as the sqlrepl_distrib and then try to initiate a SQL connection to the subscriber from there?  I've got a goofy error in my environment that's similar to yours that has to do with server SPNs, but it's low on my list of things to fix.  Failing that (or rather, if the login scenario that I describe above succeeds), do you see anything in the Windows event log on either the distributor or subscriber that might indicate what the problem is?

Comment: You just reminded me.... I did update the SPN to several values that seemed to make sense.  The error I posted is the only one I see in the eventlog of either host, it also shows up in the SMSS logs.  I did not try logging in as the sqlrepl_distrib user, but I'll try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

What's the user running the service?

Do check if the spn of the named instance is registered, and also the spn for sql server browser service, as a named instance will force the kerberos authentication to be delegated from the browser service.

And make sure that the browser service is enabled to delegate to the sql spn on windows ad.

Answer (score 0):

First check in SOL server configure manager LOG ON with what users---> for
example user log on as :-NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

check all publisher and distributor and subscriber 'logins' (for this goto your instance--> security-->logins . you must check 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' this login is there or not. if dose't have login create New login with the name 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' all publisher and distributor and subscriber.

you can right click the above login--> take properties-->usermapping--> change options-->here select that database and give permitions DB_woner and PUBLIC  to database
like thaat you can change all publisher and distributor and subscriber.

ofter that re-run your replication

Note:
here I'm LOGON with NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
and
my DATABASE is: Sudheer

Check your own what are LOGON with '????' and Database is '???' in your system!!